# Alinhar texto na vertical em relação a uma imagem

Tags: html, css

Tenho duas secções de texto em cada lado com uma imagem ao meio,e quero alinhar as secções de texto na vertical com o meio da imagem como posso fazer?Obrigado [image: <code>inserir a descrição da imagem aqui</code>]

```
<div class="fourth">
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 tituloTat">
            <h3><?php echo ($texto[103]); ?></h3>
            <h4><?php echo ($texto[111]); ?></h4>
            <img src="imgs/linhaOndulada.png" class="img-responsive">   
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4 sec4textoEsquerda apresentacao1Sec4">
            <h4><?php echo ($texto[114]); ?></h4>   
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 sec4Imagem apresentacao1Sec4">
            <img src="imgs/<?php echo $img[102]; ?>" class="img-responsive imgFrame" >
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 sec4textoDireita apresentacao1Sec4">
            <h4><?php echo ($texto[115]); ?></h4>   
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
div.fourth { width: 100%;height: auto;background-color: #ffffff;padding-top: 150px;padding-bottom: 150px;position: relative; }


div.fourth div.container div.row div.apresentacao1Sec4 { margin-top:     60px;margin-bottom: 60PX; }

div.fourth div.container div.row div.sec4Imagem img { width: 350px;height: 350px;border-radius: 50%;margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: Veja se funciona adicionar isso no CSS: div.apresentacao1Sec4{ line-height: 350px; }

Comment: Cara qual versão do Bootstrap vc está usando 3 ou 4?

Comment: O que é "texto na vertical com o meio da imagem"? É o texto em cima da imagem? ou o texto sobre a imagem? ou lado a lado mas começando e terminando nas mesmas linhas?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Sim consegui resolver.Muito obrigado pela ajuda que me deu

Comment: a versão do Bootstrap é a 3

Comment: Não deixe de escolher a melhor resposta que você achou marcando ️️✔ nela. Abs!

Comment: eu pensei em algo do genero sam como posso fazer isso?........ja encontrei o sinal de certo obrigado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Coloque uma classe no elemento que você quer alinhar (no caso o `h4`):

```
<h4 class="meio">
```

E insira no seu CSS:

```
.meio{
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

As propriedades `top` e `translateY` farão com que o elemento fique centralizado na vertical dentro do seu contêiner. Mas não está relacionado diretamente à imagem. A imagem está em outra `div`, e como as três `div`s (texto | imagem | texto) possuem a mesma altura, centralizando o texto dentro do seu contêiner fará com que fique alinhado ao meio em relação à imagem.

**Exemplo (execute em tela cheia):**

```css
div.fourth { width: 100%;height: auto;background-color: #ffffff;padding-top: 150px;padding-bottom: 150px;position: relative; }


div.fourth div.container div.row div.apresentacao1Sec4 { margin-top:     60px;margin-bottom: 60PX; }

div.fourth div.container div.row div.sec4Imagem img { width: 350px;height: 350px;border-radius: 50%;margin: 0 auto; }

.meio{
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fourth">
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 tituloTat">
            <h3>The object isn't rendered immediately. Your img property has a null value at logging time but when you open the object in the console, later, it's filled.</h3>
            <h4>The object isn't rendered immediately. Your img property has a null value at logging time but when you open the object in the console, later, it's filled.</h4>
            <img src="imgs/linhaOndulada.png" class="img-responsive">   
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4 sec4textoEsquerda apresentacao1Sec4">
            <h4 class="meio">1The object isn't rendered immediately. Your img property has a null value at logging time but when you open the object in the console, later, it's filled.</h4>   
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 sec4Imagem apresentacao1Sec4">
            <img src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" class="img-responsive imgFrame" >
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 sec4textoDireita apresentacao1Sec4">
            <h4 class="meio">2The object isn't rendered immediately. Your img property has a null value at logging time but when you open the object in the console, later, it's filled.</h4>   
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o display flex com align-items
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Você adiciona a classe na div do row

```
<div class="row flex">

    <div class="col-lg-4 sec4textoEsquerda apresentacao1Sec4">
        <h4><?php echo ($texto[114]); ?></h4>   
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 sec4Imagem apresentacao1Sec4">
        <img src="imgs/<?php echo $img[102]; ?>" class="img-responsive imgFrame" >
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 sec4textoDireita apresentacao1Sec4">
        <h4><?php echo ($texto[115]); ?></h4>   
    </div>

</div>
```

Como parece que você esta utilizando o bootstrap pode ser que ele de algum problema no mobile. Caso ele de algum problema na quebra de linha você pode utilzar a @media com a propriedade flex-wrap: wrap

Answer (score 0):

Reparei que você utiliza bootstrap 3 pela class `img-responsive`, no bootstrap 3 ainda o sistema de grid tinha algumas limitações, até te aconselho dar uma olhada na nova versão está muito boa a parte de grid e alinhamento de conteúdo.

Para fazer o que você precisa no Bootstrap 3 será necessário algumas linhas customizadas de CSS para complementar.

Você tem diversas formas para fazer da forma que você quer a primeira.

Que a sessão onde ficará texto - imagem - texto seja flexível se ajuste sem `.col`.

A segunda é com os tamanhos já pré-definidos com `.col` para cada item.

Verifique abaixo os códigos refeitos com Bootstrap v3 que creio que é a que você está utilizando.

```css
.fourth {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.fourth div,
.fourth figure {
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto!important;
flex: 1 1 auto!important;
margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container fourth">
 <div>
  <h4>Título</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a porta tellus. Donec lobortis, nibh non lacinia pellentesque, neque felis finibus justo, ac feugiat augue lectus ut orci. Duis ac volutpat ligula, sed cursus est.</p> 
 </div>

 <figure>
  <img src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX23310792.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" >
 </figure>

 <div>
  <h4>Título</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a porta tellus. Donec lobortis, nibh non lacinia pellentesque, neque felis finibus justo, ac feugiat augue lectus ut orci. Duis ac volutpat ligula, sed cursus est.</p>   
 </div>
</div>
```

A segunda forma é pré-definindo os tamanhos de cada área.

```css
.fourth > .d-flex {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.fourth div,
.fourth figure {
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto!important;
flex: 1 1 auto!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container fourth">
 <div class="row d-flex">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
   <h4>Título</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a porta tellus. Donec lobortis, nibh non lacinia pellentesque, neque felis finibus justo, ac feugiat augue lectus ut orci. Duis ac volutpat ligula, sed cursus est.</p> 
  </div>

  <figure class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
   <img src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX23310792.jpg" class="img-responsive img-circle" >
  </figure>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
   <h4>Título</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a porta tellus. Donec lobortis, nibh non lacinia pellentesque, neque felis finibus justo, ac feugiat augue lectus ut orci. Duis ac volutpat ligula, sed cursus est.</p>   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

E mais um detalhe, meu ponto de vista independe da forma que você escolher para seu projeto é que insira no `@media` que os atributos `display: flex;` sejam apenas exibidos nas resoluções acima de `992px`, mas por que? Por que no celular o atributo `display: flex;` irá tentar alinhar todos eles um ao lado do outro fazendo que todos fiquem numa linha o que será ruim para resoluções menores.

Então ficaria assim o CSS.

```css
@media(min-width: 992px) {
.fourth > .d-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.fourth div,
.fourth figure {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto!important;
  flex: 1 1 auto!important;
}
}
```

Espero ter conseguido te ajudar e ajudar a comunidade!

Answer (score -1):

Queria uma solução com CSS mas só consegui com jquery
    $('.sec4textoEsquerda').css('padding-top',$('.sec4Imagem').height()/2-$('.sec4textoEsquerda').height()/2); Obrigado